# Images not appearing in print preview - Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, print-preview

Using Windows 7. The photos(images) are not appearing in the Print preview in chrome browser - version 36.0.1985.125m onwards.  The maps works fine. 
I have attached a sample. This is happening in the Chrome alone.

Note : Works fine with CTRL + P.

Please advise, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  CTRL+P opens the print preview dialog from which you can select your printer or even print to a .pdf.

Comment: Right-click on the image that's causing problems, choose `Inspect Element`. A pane will appear. On the left hand side, a line will be highlighted. Right-click on that line, choose `Copy`. Edit your question and add the lines(s) from the clipboard. That will let us work out exactly what technique is being used to display the image and diagnose farther.

Comment: Do the images appear on the print out?

Answer (score 7):

After Pressing Ctrl+p or giving print in Chrome Select the Checkbox `Background colors and images` under the `Options`.

[image]

Comment: Tried but didn't work.

Comment: this was the solution for me

Answer (score 3):

A very simple solution is this one (and it works with firefox and Chrome/chromium):

Open a new tab. Type

```
data:text/html, <html contenteditable>
```

in the address-bar.

Thus you can use the browser as a text-editor. Best save the tab as a bookmark (see https://www.schieb.de/720201/firefox-oder-chrome-als-text-editor-benutzen).

Then copy the complete page you want to save to the editor-page. It copies all pictures together with the text.
Then it´s really simple to print (as .pdf-file) the page from the editor-page.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the image is cached before issuing the print command, especially when using document.write

The simplest way I got around the problem in Chrome was to add this to the page I want to print:

```
<div><img src="image_that_does_not_show_in_preview.png" style="display:none;"/></div>
```

This will cache the image and ensure it shows up in Chrome's print preview dialog.

Comment: Helped me a lot. My issue was image on page has additional get param, i.e. `<img src='/images/image.jpg?v=123'>`, but printable version has image without param, i.e. `<img src='/images/image.jpg'>`. So I simly added `<img src='/images/image.jpg' style='display: none'>` and it works now.

Comment: removed the whole div completely in my case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was driving me crazy. For me, it turned out that Chrome was removing images that were touching or crossing the "invisible" margin, as per the margin settings.

Setting the margin to "Minimal" or "None" made the images appear.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS to apply the display style to the img. either inline or specific enough that the print preview's applied `display:none;` is overriden.

To clarify add `style="display:block;"` to an `<img [insert style here] src"/i-am-an-image.jpg"/>` element

That solved it for me, hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

Just add the below styles to make it work 
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

Its the width of the image being set to 0 in the print which is causing the issue.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Where would the OP enter this code?